# Spring bean constructor-arg

Tags: spring, javabeans

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd"
       default-autowire="byName"> 
     <bean name="schedulerMap" class="java.util.HashMap">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="moBiScheduler" value-ref="moBiScheduler"/>
                <entry key="billJobScheduler" value-ref="billJobScheduler"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg> 
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

That's some of the XML.

In the class, I want to use `@Autowired` to inject the value of `key='moBiScheduler'` and `key='billJobScheduler'`

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, Scheduler> schedulerMap;
```

Comment: So. What is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible , you can

- autoriwre a method that takes Map and do some filtering and put the right values to schedulerMap
- Create another class MapHolder which  extends Map (it's optional) and implements ApplicationContextAware. after the injection of ApplicationContext you can retrieve schedulerMap and do some filtering and put the right value to your map , then inject this map
- you can also use BeanPostProcessor